# Create and use database function with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to create and immediatly use a database function in a single sql call.

As an example, the following works fine in PostgreSQL SQL Editor :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.get(IN nb BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT AS 'SELECT $1 + $1' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

SELECT pg_temp.get(2);
```

But when i try to use it with JPA :

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.get(IN nb BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT AS 'SELECT $1 + $1' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;\n" +
     "SELECT pg_temp.get(2);").getSingleResult();
```

I get the following error :

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
    ... 199 more
 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:381)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    ... 214 more
```

How could i make this work ?

Comment: Look at [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-sp)

Comment: The rules on my project does not allow the use stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to execute two queries at once. You need to split this into two queries:

```
int updated = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.get(IN nb BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT AS 'SELECT $1 + $1' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE").executeUpdate();
Object result = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT pg_temp.get(2)").getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I tried it too, but then i get nearly the same exception but with the "Caused by" being "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected"

Comment: Really? Wow, I did not see that one coming. So if you try `getSingleResult` it doesn't return results, and if you try `executeUpdate` it does return results?

Comment: yes, that's why i can't get it. I tried combination of request like 
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.get(IN nb BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT AS 'SELECT $1 + $1' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE; SELECT pg_temp.get(2); -- Use of function` or
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.get(IN nb BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT AS 'SELECT $1 + $1' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE; SELECT 1; -- Without using function` and with `executeUpdate`, `getSingleResult` or `getResultList`, but none worked

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. You're trying to execute two statements in one command. I'll update my answer

Comment: I see. It works fine that way. So there is no way i can get it work with only one call ? My statement is originaly from a constant so i would prefere not to split it. Is there a way to ignore the result of the function creation so that it keeps on executing the second statement ?

Comment: None that I know of, unfortunately